# Email-based sign-up in PlayJava

Tags: java, scala, authentication, playframework

Now I am researching how to implement email-based sing-up in Play Java.  However, I couldn't get any useful information, so can anyone tell me the information?  In other words, can anyone show some links or the easy example of it?

This is [the example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-playful-web-dev-1-trs-bluemix/)  written in Scala, but unfortunately I can't understand well, I am not familiar with Scala...

Any comment is welcome.

EDIT: Some people dislike this question. Maybe they think this is not a good question because I am supposed to reach some answers of this question.
However, in fact there seems to be no information that help me build email-based authentication when using Java.  In Play Scala, you have many options.  But I want to know how to realize it in Java, not Scala.  So, this question is so meaning for some people who try to build a web app in Play Java.

Comment: Maybe try a library for this https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette

Comment: There is no JavaAPI in **silhouette**.  I can find a variety of libraries which supports OAuth, but I can't see the library which enables me to implement email-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Play Authenticate library: http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   To me, this library seems to be a little bit strange, I can't run the sample application locally and the app on Heroku, neither.   Do they arrange this library well?    And yet, maybe we have no option to use this library to implement email-based authentication in Play Java?